# Se o "se" repetir duas vezes (mesmo em contextos diferentes) é errado?

Tags: conjunções

Já vi em algum versículo na bíblia a palavra "se" repetindo-se simultaneamente.

De acordo com o exemplo abaixo, qual das duas formas estariam corretas, de acordo com o contexto aplicado?

> Se se sabe ou se se sente

ou

> Se sabe-se ou se sente-se

Answer (score 11):

Não, cada uma das instâncias pertence a uma classe diferente, logo podem ser usadas uma ao lado da outra. Uma forma de ver se a frase está correta é traduzi-la para outra língua, portanto, em espanhol ficaria "Sí se (...)" e em inglês ficaria "If you (...)"; como são, claramente, palavras diferentes, está, à partida correto.

É de notar que em "Se se (...)" o primeiro *se* é uma conjunção, em quanto que o segundo é um *pronome*, que faz parte do verbo, já que este é reflexivo.

Comment: Quase de certeza (se soubermos o versículo completo podemos tirar as teimas) que _Saber_ naquele exemplo não é reflexivo. O segundo _se_ é o pronome impessoal. Ou seja, _se se sabe_ deve ser ali equivalente a _se é sabido (por alguém)_ e não a _se você se sabe_. Esta última construção é possível, mas pouco habitual: _se você se sabe capaz, vá em frente._

Answer (score 5):

**Se sabe-se** não é gramatical. **Se se sabe** é gramatical e encontra-se com alguma frequência, e não só na Bíblia. O primeiro **se** é a *conjunção*; os segundo **se** pode ser o *pronome apassivador ou pronome indefinido* (pode não ser fácil distinguir entre os dois) ou um *pronome pessoal reflexivo*. ([Ver aqui os vários significados de *se*.](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/funcoes-do-se/))

A construção mais frequente é com o pronome apassivador ou pronome indefinido. Por exemplo:

> **Sabe-se** que ele é incompetente. (= *é sabido que ele é incompetente*)
>
> *Se* **se sabe** que ele é incompetente, por que razão o contrataram?

O **sabe-se** da primeira frase passa a **se sabe** na segunda, porque esta começa com a conjunção *se*, o que exige a próclise (pronome **se** antes do verbo), e assim ficam dois *ses* legitimamente lado a lado. Precisamente porque a conjunção *se* exige a próclise, *se sabe-se* não é gramatical. (*Sabe-se que ele é incompetente* é norma culta; *se sabe que ele é incompetente*, usado informalmente no ptBR mas não no ptPT, tornaria o exemplo ainda mais simples.)

Uma construção com conjunção *se* + pronome pessoal reflexivo **se** poderia resultar de, por exemplo:

> *Se* você **se** sente mal, é melhor ir ao médico.

Aproveitando a possibilidade que o Português oferece de omitir o sujeito, *você* neste caso, obtemos de novo dois *ses* lado a lado:

> *Se* **se** sente mal, é melhor ir ao médico.

Novamente, a conjunção *se* exige **se sente** e proíbe *sente-se*.